# Rewriting code using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
void rmchr(char*string, char ch) //string function
{
   int i; //position in string variable
   int j; //updated variable of i to the end of string
   for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) // i iterates through the string
   {
      if(string[i] == ch) //checks if given character is equal to char at ith position
      {
         for(j=i; string[j] != '\0'; j++) //loop from i to end of string
         {
            string[j] = string[j + 1]; //swaps value of next char so matching char is placed at end of string
         }
         string[j] = '\0';
         i--; //decrease i by 1
      }
   }
}
```

> I need this code to be rewritten using pointers. Please help.
>   The program takes a string and a character and removes all occurrences of the character from the string. I haven't included all code as this is the only code that needs to be rewritten using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `string[i]` is equivalent to `*(string + i)`.

Comment: This code is already using pointers.

Comment: It's already using a pointer.

Comment: I turned this in to my teacher and she said i need to use pointers so I'm just confused.

Comment: `char*` is a pointer, and you're using it.... They probably meant to use pointer arithmetic which the first comment shows an example.

Comment: But the entire code needs to be written using pointers

Comment: I think you should've asked your teacher for clarification.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes thats what she meant

Comment: @Chief Using the *(q+1) and q[1] are both considerd pointer arithmetics when used on pointers. So it sounds like your teacher is incompetent.

Comment: @Fredrik, it's not my teacher. I'm not a C language lawyer but I would call that equivalent but not the same. It's a shorthand that gets compiled, IIRC, into explicit pointer arithmetic. So, as is usual when learning programming, you have to do it the hard and/or inconvenient way before you use a mechanism that hides stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not a service to write entire modules of code, but for pointed questions of when you've gotten stuck after attempting on your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate by incrementing a pointer (rather than using array lookups). In many cases however, the compiler will be able to optimize both versions to attain similar performance.

```
for (char *p = string; *p; ++p) {
    if (*p == ch) {
        for (char *q = p; *q; ++q) {
            *q = *(q + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And `*p != '\0'` written customarily as `*p`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: absolutely!

Comment: I hate that custom. Hate it, hate it, hate it. I want my conditions to look like conditions.

Comment: Using the *(q+1) and q[1] are both considerd pointer arithmetics when used on a pointer.

Comment: @HackSaw well, you're entitled to your opinion as well. I checked K&R and the example code there does seem to use `!= `\0`'

Comment: @Fredrik ... well considering that you can use them *only* on a pointer...

Comment: @ Antti Haapala: Yeah, I know I'm tilting at windmills. I've been burned by a surprise -1.

Comment: @Antti q[1] can be used on arrays aswell..

Comment: @Fredrik no, the array always decays to a pointer, the `[]` can only used on values of pointer type. Same with function calls - you can *only* apply the function call operator to a value of type pointer-to-function, which is why dereferencing a function pointer to call it always looks funny to me.

Comment: @Antti arrays do decay to pointers in many contexts but NOT ALL. And [] can be used in those contexts to access array elements.

Comment: @Fredrik Arrays decay in *all* contexts except when they're directly the target of `&` or `sizeof`. `[]` requires [one of the operands to be a pointer](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1). For arrays this happens through pointer decay.